# Python Numpy 2D array aligned without brackets

Tags: python, numpy

I want to print 2D array without brackets and so that elements are aligned. I went through bunch of posts and manged to remove brackets but then elements are not aligned anymore and if I print my array like it is, elements are aligned but then there are brackets.

My code is simple

```
a = np.asarray(b._BaseArray__data).reshape(3,3)
print(a)
```

Where b._BaseArray__data represents list.

So how can I print my array that will be aligned and without brackets and commas?

Current result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]
 [5, 6, 7, 8]
 [9,10,11,12]]
```

And I want it like this:

```
1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8
9 10 11 12
```

Comment: You can just use [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for formatting, or provide a `separator` argument to `print` and loop through the array

Comment: How does your data look like? How should the output look like? You're getting down-votes because you do not provide all the necessary information for us to help you. Please add a working, minimal example to your question!

Comment: There I added current and wanted result

Comment: That sounds like a lot more work than it's worth.  How flexible do you want to be in alignment?  Just handling this simple example, or something more general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do what you want with two nested `for`loops:

```
import numpy as np

# example data
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])


def print_array(arr):
    """
    prints a 2-D numpy array in a nicer format
    """
    for a in arr:
        for elem in a:
            print("{}".format(elem).rjust(3), end="")
        print(end="\n")


# call the printing function
print_array(arr)
```

prints:

```
  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8
  9 10 11 12
```